# How do I take off the last comma in a random line of numbers?

Tags: python

I am creating a code that picks a random group of seven numbers between 1-40. I want the numbers to be separated with a comma *except* the last number. How can I take the last comma off?

The code is this:

```
import random
def lottery():
    sum=0
    for num in range(7):
        num1 = random.randint(1,40)
        sum += num1
        print(str(num1),end=',')
lottery()
```

I want this to be the result:
10,4,3,3,2,1,9

Comment: [tag:python-requests] is a specific library and that print syntax doesn't work at all in [tag:python-2.7].

Answer (score 0):

Add the values to a list and `join()` them together

```
import random

def lottery():
    values = []
    sum=0
    for num in range(7):
        num1 = random.randint(1,40)
        sum += num1
        values.append(str(num1))
    print(','.join(values))

lottery()
```